# Create a model from the given text (linear programming/optimization)

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I'm practicing for a linear programming test and here is a task I like to see if I did it correct and if not maybe how to do it correctly? Need to create a mathematical model whose requirements are represented by linear relationships.

> A company wants produce two different kind of cars, $A$ and $B$. The
>   production process is set up by these two things: installation and
>   finishing. For the installation of $A$, the company needs $4$ hours 
>   and for the installation of $B$ they need $6$ hours. The finishing
>   requires $6$ hours for car $A$ and $3$ hours for $B$. The profit for
>   each car $A$ is $4000$ USD and for $B$ is $3000$ USD.
>
> Dependent on other projects, the company has $720$ hours time for the
>   installation and $480$ hours for the finishing within a
>   production-cycle. The management requests for the duration of a cycle
>   at least $20$ cars of kind $A$ and at least $30$ cars of kind $B$.
>
> How many cars of each kind the company needs to produce within one
>   cycle such that every (production-)condition is unhurt, the
>   requirements of the management satisfied and the maximum profit is
>   achieved?

---

Due to the long text, I like to keep it as short as possible. I have the following model:

$4000x_1 +3000x_2 \rightarrow \min$

$4x_1+6x_2 \geq 720$

$6x_1+3x_2 \geq 480$

$x_1 \geq 20$

$x_2 \geq 30$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The company wants to maximize the profit: $4000x_1 +3000x_2 \rightarrow \color{red}{\max}$

> The company has (at most) 720 hours time for the installation:

$4x_1+6x_2 \color{red}{\leq} 720$

> ... and (at most) 480 hours for the finishing within a
>   production-cycle:

$6x_1+3x_2 \color{red}{\leq} 480$

The other two constraints look O.K.

$x_1 \geq 20$

$x_2 \geq 30$

The linear programming can be solved graphically or with Simplex algorithm.